# UltraVNC port forwarding

Tags: windows-7, networking, port-forwarding, port, ultravnc

It has been a while i doing the port forwarding for UltraVNC. I have two routers with following information. Please help me with the port forwarding config for UltraVNC.

**Dlink DIR-615**
Function : Internet Modem and Wireless AP
IP : 192.168.5.1

**Linksys WRT54GL**
Function : Wireless AP and DHCP
IP : 192.168.3.1
Connection : Connected to Dlink DIR 615

**PC running UltraVNC Server**
IP : 192.168.3.154
Function : connected to Linksys WRT54GL

I would like to access the PC using UltraVNC from external (internet).

Comment: Any particular reason you're (probably) doing double NAT?

Comment: the guy who setup the internet configured my routers in this way. So i am figuring out how to configure using this existing setup..

Answer (score 0):

Double NAT is not a particularly advisable way to go as it complicates things, but you can get it to work. Assuming your VNC server is running on the default port, just forward port 5900 through the D-Link DIR-615 to the IP of the Linksys WRT54GL, and then on the WRT54GL forward port 5900 over to the IP of your VNC server.

Not taking into account any software firewall(s) you may be running on your PC, once you set up both of those port forwarders on the routers you should be able to connect to the VNC service on your PC from the Internet.

Comment: i tried to port forward 5900 from dlink to linksys, but getting error saying that the ip should be in same subnet.

Comment: Forward the port from the D-Link to the WAN IP of the Linksys. It'll be in the 192.168.5.x range. And on that note, make sure the WAN IP on the Linksys is a static IP, not DHCP, otherwise the IP address may change at some point and this forwarder will stop working.

Comment: I have configured port 5900 to linksys WAN IP : 192.168.5.102. Then in linksys, the source address should be 192.168.5.102 -> PC IP is it ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify a source address when configuring the WRT54GL. Your interface looks like this, correct? http://ui.linksys.com/WRT54GL/4.30.0/Applications.htm

Comment: In the Application field type VNC, then in the Start and End fields enter 5900, select Protocol TCP (or leave as Both) and then in the IP address box fill in the IP of your PC, 192.168.3.154

Comment: i using tomato firmware for linksys

Comment: Finally It works !!!... Thank you so much for the help

Comment: No problem. I was just about to provide more detailed instructions specifically for Tomato, but I'm glad to hear you got it working!